# Syntax for Combining BETWEEN and LIKE

Tags: postgresql

I have a syntax, but it doesn't work.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM aqua.reading
WHERE
  CAST(reading.pres_date AS VARCHAR)
  BETWEEN LIKE '2022-10-18%' AND LIKE '2022-10-18%'
```

it says:

```
ERROR:  type "like" does not exist
LINE 1: ... WHERE CAST(reading.pres_date AS VARCHAR) BETWEEN LIKE '2022...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42704
Character: 77
```

I am trying to get all the data with timestamp and timezone and implement a date range

Comment: There is no such syntax. LIKE is used for character strings, not dates, and there is no BETWEEN LIKE.  You don't need it anyway. Remove the `%` from your two dates and just use BETWEEN.

Comment: You also don't need to CAST the dates. Just use BETWEEN on the date values.

Comment: what should i do to get all data correspond to the date and range it over using BETWEEN?

Comment: This is the correct syntax: `WHERE reading.pres_date BETWEEN '2022-10-18' AND '2022-10-18'`

Comment: Additional note: using `BETWEEN .. AND ..`, when beginning and ending dates are the same, makes no sense.

Comment: `... WHERE reading.pres_date = '2022-10-18'`. Assuming `reading.pres_date` is actually a `date` type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare dates (or timestamps) as strings. Compare them to proper date (or timestamp) values. Given the fact that you use the same "date" but with a wildcard at the end, I am assuming(!) that `pres_date` is in fact a `timestamp` column and you want to find all rows with a given date regardless of the time value of the timestamp.

The best approach is to use a range query with `>=` ("greater than or equal) on the lower value and `<` (strictly lower than) on the *next* day:

```
SELECT *
FROM aqua.reading
WHERE reading.pres_date >= DATE '2022-10-18' 
  AND reading.pres_date < DATE '2022-10-19'
```

Alternatively you can cast the timestamp to a date and use the `=` operator if you really want to pick just one day:

```
SELECT *
FROM aqua.reading
WHERE cast(reading.pres_date as DATE) = DATE '2022-10-18'
```

However that will not make use of a potential index on `pres_date` so is likely to be slower than the range query from the first solution